# Probability and Wilcoxon rank sum test

Tags: probability, expectation

The Wilcoxon rank sum test is a widely used procedure for assessing whether two groups of observations come from the same distribution. Let group 1 consist of i.i.d. X1,…, Xm with CDF F and group 2 consist of i.i.d. Y1,…, Yn with CDF G, with all of these r.v.s independent. Assume that the probability of 2 of the observations being equal is 0 (this will be true if the distributions are continuous).

After the m + n observations are obtained, they are listed in increasing order, and each is assigned a rank between 1 and m + n: the smallest has rank 1, the second smallest has rank 2, etc. Let Rj be the rank of Xj among all the observations for 1 ≤ j ≤ m, and let R = ∑mj = 1 Rj be the sum of the ranks for group 1.

Intuitively, the Wilcoxon rank sum test is based on the idea that a very large value of R is evidence that observations from group 1 are usually larger than observations from group 2 (and vice versa if R is very small). But how large is “very large” and how small is “very small” ? Answering this precisely requires studying the distribution of the test statistic R.

(a) The null hypothesis in this setting is that F = G. Show that if the null hypothesis is true, then E(R) = m(m + n + 1)/2.

(b) The power of a test is an important measure of how good the test is about saying to reject the null hypothesis if the null hypothesis is false. To study the power of the Wilcoxon rank sum stest, we need to study the distribution of R in general. So for this part, we do not assume F = G. Let p = P(X1>Y1). Find E(R) in terms of m, n, p.

Comment: It's hard to identify what you are asking here.  It's as if you simply copied some text from an exam or textbook discussion.  Please explain what difficulty you encountered when attempting this problem, so that Answers can better be directed to enlighten you.

Comment: Basically I am stuck on second question My answer to the problem is = m*( (m-1) *0.5 + np)  I am using indicator random variables to define Rj in terms of Xj > other random variables and then using Fundamental bridge to calculate E(Rj) Any insights on how this can be done ?

Comment: Just to elaborate more here is what I am doing  E(R) = E(R1 + R2+ ......Rm)   = mE(Rj) because of symmetry and E(Rj) = E(I1,j + I2,j....Im+n,j)   Now Ik,j = 0.5 if we are comparing to X1 or X2 or X3....  and = p if we are comparing to Y1,Y2....Yn  that leads us to E(Rj) = (1/2*(m-1) + np)

Comment: You're very close to the answer. E(Rj) is what you calculated plus one.